# How can execute a MySQL query with multiple WHERE-clauses?

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

how would you do a mysql query where a user can choose from multiple options. Fox example I have a form that user can use to search for houses. Now I have a select box where you can chosse whether you want a house, a flat or whatever. Then I have a second box where you can choose for example the city you want the house or flat to be in. And maybe another one with the maximum price.

Now how would you do the mysql query? My problem is, I would do it like that:
if($_POST["house_type"] != 0) {
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE type = '".$_POST["house_type"]."'");
}
But now I only have the case that someone has chosen a house type but not any other option. So do I have to do an "if" for every possible combination of selected elements?

To emphasize my problem:

```
if(!isset($_POST["house_type"])) {

            if($_POST["something"] == 0) {
        $search_select = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM housedata WHERE something = $_POST["whatever"]);

            }
            elseif($_POST["something"] != 0) {
        $search_select = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM housedata  something = $_POST["whatever"] AND somethingelse = 'whatever');
            }
        }



elseif(!isset($_POST["house_type"])) {


        if($_POST["something"] == 0) {
        $search_select = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM housedata WHERE something = $_POST["whatever"]);

            }
            elseif($_POST["something"] != 0) {
        $search_select = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM housedata  something = $_POST["whatever"] AND somethingelse = 'whatever');
            }
        }
```

Now imagine I had like 10 or 20 different select boxes, input fields and checkboxes and I would have to do a mysql query depending on what of these boxes and fiels and checkboxes is filled. This would be a code that is extremely complicated, slow and horrible. So is there a possibility to make a mysql query like:

```
SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE house_data = '".$whatever."' AND (if(isset($_POST["something"])) { whatever = '".$whatever2."' } AND ...;
```

You get what I mean? Its a bit complicated to explain but actually its a very important question and probably easy to answer.

Thank you for your help!
phpheini

Comment: Loop through and concatenate all options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate the WHERE clause prior to running the SQL.

A short example:

```
$whereClause = "";

if ($_POST['opt1']) {
    $opt1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['opt1']);
    $whereClause .= "AND opt1='$opt1'";
}

if ($_POST['opt2']) {
    $opt2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['opt2']);
    $whereClause .= "AND opt2='$opt2'";
}

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 ".$whereClause);
```

Comment: Thank you! Very nice and easy!

Comment: Just remember to escape everything that comes through $_POST to prevent SQL injections :)

Comment: @lethalMango - $10 bucks says he doesn't ;)

Comment: using mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Sure is, depending if safety is up your priority list then using prepared statements is a better option - check out PDO / MySQLi

Comment: Cool, thats interesting. But I cant find what exactly makes it more secure than normal Mysql?

Answer (score 1):

To point you a little bit into the right direction, try something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["something"]))
{
    $where = " AND whatever = '".$whatever2."'";
}
else    $where = '';

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE house_data = '".$whatever."'".$where);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was allready thinking of this, but I thought there is a mysql function or something.

Answer (score 1):

```
$where = array();
if($_POST["something"]) {
    $where[]  = " something =".$_POST["something"];
}
if($_POST["something2"]) {
   $where[]  = " something2=".$_POST["something2"];
}
.
.
.
//build where string
$where_ = !(empty($where) ? " WHERE ".implode(" AND ",$where) : "";
//build sql
$sql = "SELECT * ... ".$where;
```

Answer (score 0):

write some simple query builder

```
$where = array();
if($_POST["something"]) {


$where[]  = sprintf(" something='%s'",$_POST["something"]);
```

//sprintf - prevent SQL injection
    }

```
if($_POST["something2"]) {


$where[]  = sprintf(" something2='%s'",$_POST["something2"]);
}
//build where string
$where_str = " WHERE ".implode(" AND ",$where);
//build sql
$sql = "SELECT * ... $where_str";
```

Comment: Thank you, but what exactly is sprintf doing in this case?

Comment: It casts $_POST variable to string and escapes special chars which prevents from SQL injections see picture http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your search string separately but the format is simply

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE number = {$number} AND sentence = '{$sentence}';
```

Since you are creating the search term based on PHP logic do this:

```
$search = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE ";
if(isset($whatever)) $search .= "something = '{$whatever}'";
if(isset($whateverelse)) $search .= " AND somethingelse = '{$whateverelse}'";
$search_select = mysql_query($search);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Why did you put the variables into brackets ({ and })? Is it better than using '".$number."'?

Comment: If `$whatever` wasn't set but `$whateverelse` was you'd end up with `"SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE AND somethingelse = '{$whateverelse}'"`;

Comment: whas that an answer to my question?